# How to stop a video in AVPlayer?

Tags: objective-c, avfoundation, avplayer

I am using this code to play video file using avplayer how do I stop it

```
 [videoView setHidden:NO];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path2 = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:saveFileName];
    NSURL *url1 = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath: path2];
    videoPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:url1] ;
    self.avPlayerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:videoPlayer];

    //[self willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation];
    avPlayerLayer.frame = videoView.bounds;
    [self.videoView.layer addSublayer: avPlayerLayer];

    [self.videoPlayer play];
```

I tried this it doesn't work

```
    //[self.videoPlayer release];
```

Answer (score 70, accepted):

[AVPlayer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) does not have a method named `stop`. You can `pause` or set `rate` to 0.0.

Answer (score 34):

I usually seekToTime 0.0, then pause. It work perfectly with me. :)

```
[self.videoPlayer seekToTime:CMTimeMake(0, 1)];
[self.videoPlayer pause];
```

Answer (score 27):

If you dont want to set the av player to nil, a better approach might be :

```
videoPlayer.replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem(nil)
```

Comment: This option is not Swift compatible.

Comment: Without doing this `replaceCurrentItem..` I find that the networkActivityIndicator never goes away and the app uses a lot of battery power, even when the player has been paused and set to nil.

Comment: @HolaSoyEduFelizNavidad, yes it is. You can do `.replaceCurrentItem(with: nil)`

Answer (score 23):

You can pause and set AVPlayer object value to nil .

And in your code you can use this :

```
[self.videoPlayer pause];
[self.avPlayerLayer removeFromSuperlayer];
self.videoPlayer = nil;
```

Answer (score 16):

We have swift protocol extensions - rejoice.

```
extension AVPlayer {
   func stop(){
    self.seek(to: CMTime.zero)
    self.pause()
   }
}
```