# Impossible to stop AVPlayer

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

I am currently testing the use of AVPlayer with audio streaming url, using **Swift**. There are [play()](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayer_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/AVPlayer/play) and [pause()](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayer_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/AVPlayer/pause) methods, but the problem is that, pausing only, the stream remains cached in the device.

Here is my test code :

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let player = AVPlayer(URL: NSURL(string: "http://streaming.radio.rtl.fr/rtl-1-48-192")!)

    @IBOutlet weak var btnPlay: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()            
    }

    @IBAction func btnPress(sender: AnyObject) {
        if (btnPlay.titleLabel?.text == "Play") {
            initPlayer()
            btnPlay.setTitle("Stop", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        } else {
            stopPlayer()
            btnPlay.setTitle("Play", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        }
    }

    func initPlayer()  {
        player.play()
    }

    func stopPlayer() {
        // player.currentItem = nil // Last thing I tried, but generate an error
        player.pause()
    }
}
```

**Here are the issues when trying somethings :**

`player = nil` : "Cannot assign a value of type 'NilLiteralCOnvertible' to a value of type 'AVPlayer'"

`player.currentItem = nil` : "Cannot assign to property: 'currentItem' is a get-only property"

---

I tried everything, even through [AVQueuePlayer](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVQueuePlayer_Class/index.html) without any effective result. (obviously, since I only have one item in my case).

How to **stop AVPlayer** or **destroy his instance** ?

Comment: `player = nil` or `player.currentItem = nil`?

Comment: @JAL, `player` is an instance of AVPlayer, so I can't just do it. Please see the function `stopPlayer()`, I have already test this

Comment: What error are you getting when you try to set the player to nil?  Also, have you tried removing the player's currentItem like I suggested?

Comment: @JAL, please see my question updated

Comment: You can't mutate a `let` constant.  Change the declaration to `var`.

Comment: @JAL I always confuse the two. Thank you for allowing me to fill this important gap!

Comment: @JAL have you know how to play continues audio after destroyed that ViewController on we have created instance of AVPlayer.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you declare `player` as an optional variable, you can then set the player to `nil` to deallocate it.

Silly example but it shows what happens:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var btnPlay: UIButton!

    var player:AVPlayer?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func btnPress(sender: AnyObject) {
        if (btnPlay.titleLabel?.text == "Play") {
            initPlayer()
            btnPlay.setTitle("Stop", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        } else {
            stopPlayer()
            btnPlay.setTitle("Play", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        }
    }

    func initPlayer()  {
        if let play = player {
            print("playing")
            play.play()
        } else {
            print("player allocated")
            player = AVPlayer(URL: NSURL(string: "http://streaming.radio.rtl.fr/rtl-1-48-192")!)
            print("playing")
            player!.play()
        }
    }

    func stopPlayer() {
        if let play = player {
            print("stopped")
            play.pause()
            player = nil
            print("player deallocated")
        } else {
            print("player was already deallocated")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm sure your solution works, but so how to reallocate the player when re-enter in function `initPlayer()` ?

Comment: @EricAya  have you know how to play continues audio after destroyed that ViewController on we have created instance of AVPlayer.

Answer (score 67):

From this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17831764/how-to-stop-a-video-in-avplayer) I found the best solution to completely stop AVPlayer before you leave or start a new player:

```
videoPlayer.replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem(nil)
```

[Update] For SWIFT 3:

```
player.replaceCurrentItem(with: nil)
```

---

Note for 2023. In the case of queue player, it's

```
qp = AVQueuePlayer()
...
qp.removeAllItems()
```

Comment: Have you know how to play continues audio after destroyed that ViewController on we have created instance of AVPlayer.

Comment: This works! For swift3: videoPlayer.replaceCurrentItem(with: nil)

Answer (score 10):

**SWIFT 3 Version:**

```
player.replaceCurrentItem(with: nil)
```

Comment: player.pause()

player.replaceCurrentItem(with: nil)